# How to securely store Azure DevOps PAT token in a GitHub repo?

Tags: python, github, azure-devops, basic-authentication, python-keyring

My GitHub action would try to get a python package from Azure DevOps Artifacts. It needs Azure DevOps credentials to access that package. I made it work using Basic HTTP Authentication.

```
https://username:password@pypi.company.com/simple
pip install your-package --index-url https://pypi.company.com/
```

However, I don't want to expose my password (PAT token) like this and I want to store it securely so that GitHub would get the PAT token on each build and download the package.

In Jenkins, we can store this in credentials but I am not able to find a similar place in GitHub.

What is the best place I can get my password from? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets). To add repo-specific secrets, go to a repo and navigate to Settings, then Secrets. Or build your own URL to get there based on this template:

`https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>/settings/secrets/actions`

**EDIT:**
For using these secrets in a workflow, see [Use encrypted secrets in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow). One thing to take into account is proper quoting:

> If you must pass secrets within a command line, then enclose them within the proper quoting rules. Secrets often contain special characters that may unintentionally affect your shell. To escape these special characters, use quoting with your environment variables.

Comment: I have added a secret. Could you let me know how to access that secret from GitHub workflow and pass the value to pip install requirements.txt file please? I tried `${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}`. It is not working

Comment: There's a section about that in the GitHub documentation: [Use encrypted secrets in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow). `${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}` should work, please check if there's anything else going on. For instance: _If you must pass secrets within a command line, then enclose them within the proper quoting rules. Secrets often contain special characters that may unintentionally affect your shell. To escape these special characters, use quoting with your environment variables._